# dplyr/ data table subtract values based on condition

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a data frame that looks like the following:

```
quant_final_means <- data.frame( exposure_time_factor = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("200ms", "500ms"), class = "factor"),
protein_factor = c("background", "background", "EpQ_11_prot_0.25", "EpQ_11_prot_0.25", "EpQ_11_prot_0.5", "EpQ_11_prot_0.5", "EpQ_11_prot_1", "EpQ_11_prot_1", "rK39_prot_0.01", "rK39_prot_0.01", "rK39_prot_0.1", "rK39_prot_0.1", "serum", "serum", "background", "background", "EpQ_11_prot_0.25", "EpQ_11_prot_0.25", "EpQ_11_prot_0.5", "EpQ_11_prot_0.5", "EpQ_11_prot_1", "EpQ_11_prot_1", "rK39_prot_0.01", "rK39_prot_0.01", "rK39_prot_0.1", "rK39_prot_0.1", "serum", "serum"),
serum_factor = c("NEHC", "VL", "NEHC", "VL", "NEHC", "VL", "NEHC", "VL", "NEHC", "VL", "NEHC", "VL", "NEHC", "VL", "NEHC", "VL", "NEHC", "VL", "NEHC", "VL", "NEHC", "VL", "NEHC", "VL", "NEHC", "VL", "NEHC", "VL"),
avg_fluorescence = c(24139.615, 25796.83875, 24242.2557142857, 26019.7985714286, 25369.1971428571, 30682.4342857143, 26148.9542857143, 29101.9914285714, 24121.2328571429, 32350.1428571429, 24142.0014285714, 62122.6628571429, 57192.968, 53372.702, 40067.6985714286, 38922.4814285714, 40243.0528571429, 38932.78, 42290.35, 48867.015, 43334.3925, 46181.4542857143, 40383.8257142857, 57257.7614285714, 40378.8071428571, 65535, 65535, 65524.968) )
```

Basically what I am trying to do is to create another column (called `avg_fluorescence_minus_background`) in which I will subtract the `background` value (depending on `exposure_time_factor` and `serum_factor`) from the `avg_fluorescence` for each row.

For example, considering the third row (`exposure_time_factor=="200ms"` and `serum_factor=="NEHC"` I would have 24242.26−24139.62 = 102.64. For the fourth row (`exposure_time_factor=="200ms"` and `serum_factor=="VL"` I would have 26019.80 - 25796.84 = 222.96 and so forth, for all the rows of the table.

Starting with `exposure_time_factor=="200ms`, I have tried the following code:

```
quant_final_means %>% filter(exposure_time_factor=="200ms") %>% mutate(avg_fluorescence_minus_background = ifelse(test = serum_factor=="NEHC", yes = avg_fluorescence - (filter(protein_factor=="background", serum_factor=="NEHC")) %>% select(avg_fluorescence)), no = avg_fluorescence - (filter(protein_factor=="background", serum_factor=="VL")) %>% select(avg_fluorescence))
```

But I got the following error message when trying to run this code:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

Any solution with `dplyr` or perhaps `data.table`

Comment: I think you need is `quant_final_means %>% filter(exposure_time_factor=="200ms") %>% mutate(avg_fluorescence_minus_background = avg_fluorescence - avg_fluorescence[serum_factor == "NEHC" & protein_factor=='background'])`

Comment: Unfortunately not quite. The thing is that, depending on what is under `serum_factor` (VL or NEHC), I will have to subtract the corresponding background value (24139.62 for NEHC and 25796.84 for VL). Your code fixed the `serum_factor=="NEHC`, such that I get the wrong values for all rows which have `serum_factor=="VL"`.

Comment: I misread the question.  Corrected it in the solution

Comment: thanks it works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can either do a group by operation with `serum_factor` and then create the column

```
library(dplyr)
quant_final_means %>% 
    filter(exposure_time_factor=="200ms") %>% 
    group_by(serum_factor) %>% 
    mutate(avg_fluorescence_minus_background = avg_fluorescence -
                                         avg_fluorescence[protein_factor=='background'])
```

---

or `spread` to 'wide' format, then this can be easily subtracted, finally change it into 'long' format with `gather`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
quant_final_means %>% 
     filter(exposure_time_factor=="200ms")  %>%
     spread(serum_factor, avg_fluorescence) %>%
     mutate_at(vars('NEHC', 'VL'), funs(. - .[protein_factor=='background'])) %>%
     gather(serum_factor, avg_fluorescence, NEHC:VL)
```